# Why doesn't this Regex for picking items out of multiline entries work?

Tags: java, regex

I have this String. I am trying to pull the interface, nameif and security-level from each entry.

```
!
interface OUTSIDE
 nameif OUTSIDE
 security-level 0
 ip address 47.237.34.219 255.255.255.248 standby 47.237.34.220 
 authentication key eigrp 20 ***** key-id 20
 authentication mode eigrp 20 md5
!
interface QA
 nameif QA
 security-level 100
 ip address 47.237.34.89 255.255.255.248 standby 47.237.34.90 
 authentication key eigrp 20 ***** key-id 20
 authentication mode eigrp 20 md5
!
interface QASUSEENCEXT
 nameif QASUSEENCEXT
 security-level 93
 ip address 47.77.146.1 255.255.254.0 standby 47.77.146.2 
!
interface QASUSEENCSNSTV
 nameif QASUSEENCSNSTV
 security-level 80
 ip address 47.77.140.1 255.255.254.0 standby 47.77.140.2 

!
interface QAWINSECDB
 nameif QAWINSECDB
 security-level 80
 ip address 47.77.154.1 255.255.254.0 standby 47.77.154.2 
!
interface WIN_HCS_QA_CTRL
 nameif WIN_HCS_QA_CTRL
 security-level 96
 ip address 47.77.158.1 255.255.254.0 standby 47.77.158.2 
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet0/7.600
 description VIRT_HYPERVISOR
 nameif VIRT_HYPERVISOR
 security-level 96
 ip address 47.77.168.1 255.255.255.0 standby 47.77.168.2 
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet0/7.601
 nameif VIRT_CONTL_NET
 security-level 96
 ip address 47.77.169.1 255.255.255.0 standby 47.77.169.2 
!
interface DEV
 nameif DEV
 security-level 80
 ip address 47.237.34.97 255.255.255.248 standby 47.237.34.98 
 authentication key eigrp 20 ***** key-id 20
 authentication mode eigrp 20 md5
!
interface SUSE_BLUE_ENC_EXT
 nameif SUSE_BLUE_ENC_EXT
 security-level 80
 ip address 47.77.22.1 255.255.254.0 standby 47.77.22.2 
!
interface DEVSUSEENCSNSTV
 nameif DEVSUSEENCSNSTV
 security-level 80
 ip address 47.77.14.1 255.255.254.0 standby 47.77.14.2 
!
interface BACKUPNET
 nameif BACKUPNET
 security-level 80
 ip address 47.77.24.1 255.255.255.0 standby 47.77.24.2 
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet0/8.700
 nameif VIRT_HYPERVISOR_DEV
 security-level 96
 ip address 47.77.35.1 255.255.255.0 standby 47.77.35.2 
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet0/8.701
 nameif VIRT_CONTL_NET_DEV
 security-level 96
 ip address 47.77.36.1 255.255.255.0 standby 47.77.36.2
```

I have created this Regex:

```
((?:interface\s)(?<interface>\w+.*))(?:\n\s.*)((?:\n\snameif\s)(?<nameif>\w+))?(?:\n\ssecurity-level\s)(?<level>\d+)
```

It does not seem to be working correctly in Java. Can you guys help me out?

```
        if (split1.contains("show run interface")) {
            String showInt = split1;
            String intRegex = "((?:interface\\s)(?<interface>\\w+.*))(?:\\n\\s.*)?((?:\\n\\snameif\\s)(?<nameif>\\w+))?(?:\\n\\ssecurity-level\\s)(?<level>\\d+)";//"";
            Pattern pint = Pattern.compile(intRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher m = pint.matcher(showInt);
           // System.out.println(showInt);
            while (m.find()) {
               String interfaceS=m.group("interface");
               String nameif=m.group("nameif");
               String securityLevel=m.group("level");
                System.out.println("interface=" +interfaceS );
                System.out.println("nameif=" + nameif);
                System.out.println("securityLevel=" + securityLevel);
            }

        }
```

Comment: you're trying to use regexes on xml? You shouldn't...

Comment: Try using a xml parser...

Comment: @MarcB, @brso05, why do you think he's trying to parse XML? The `(?<X>...)` syntax is a *named capturing groups*.

Comment: Yes, I'm using named capturing groups. I made a mistake on my original post and included the wrong code snippet. It should be clearer now.

Comment: Is your whole snippet in one huge String (`split1`)?

Comment: I should also add that the regex works on regex101.com, but when i plug it into Java, it does not.

Comment: yes, the whole snippet is one huge string. The idea is that each iteration of m.find will be the named groups of each interface

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Are there errors? The wrong text is matched? Nothing is matched?

Comment: It just comes back with no matches. No hits on m.find.

Comment: You should note that regex101.com is not for the Java dialect of regex. Try [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) instead.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fB1tL9/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regexp is messed up.

- I see no need to sprinkle the code with non-capturing groups. It just clutters the expression with parentheses
- `\s` matches newlines too, so no need to do `\s\n\s` stuff
- Note that `\w+.*` matches `\w` once or more times, and then `.*` matches *anything* greedily 0 or more times. (You probably meant to just put `\w+` I believe)

This seems to work:

```
String intRegex = "(?<=interface\\s)(?<interface>[^\n]+)\\n.*?"
                + "(?<=nameif\\s)(?<nameif>[^\n]+)\\n.*?"
                + "(?<=security-level\\s)(?<level>\\d+)";
```

Comment: But what if he had text that has the strings on the same line? `\s\n\s` is *requiring* a newline, `\s*` is just *allowing* it.

Comment: That's true. That wasn't the case in his example input though. Let's wait and see if OP comments on this.

Comment: Not quite. If you notice, there is one line with the "description" tag, and your regex above skips that.

Comment: You also need to modify the "interface\\s*(?<interface>\\w+)\\s*" to be "interface\\s*(?<interface>\\w+.*)\\s*" to capture all the interfaces

Comment: all the tags are optional. So in the case of the description tag, it is present sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: no, still dropping the interface TenGigabitEthernet0/7.600
 description VIRT_HYPERVISOR
 nameif VIRT_HYPERVISOR
 security-level 96
 ip address 47.77.168.1 255.255.255.0 standby 47.77.168.2

Comment: Like i said, description may be present sometimes, and may not be other times, depending on if someone put a description.

Comment: Try using `DOTALL` instead of `MULTILINE`.

Comment: That's awesome for the most part, just had to .trim the m.group to get rid of the \n. Other than that, this works.